# Vue.js Component combined with Laravel Form Validation (i.e. passing an initial value for data)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

After much Googling and finding the Vue.js forum down, I am ready to give up.

I'm creating a Postcode Lookup component, and everything was working well until I tried to combine it with Laravel's form validation - particularly when there's an error, and the form re-fills the old values.

Hopefully I cover everything here. I have a form input partial that I use which generates every form input. It also uses Laravel's `old(...)` value if present.

The issue is because there's a default value (in this case for postcode and address) of an empty string, this overrides the value attribute of Postcode input, and the content of the Address textarea.

In made up land, the ideal would be:

```
data : function() {
    return {
        postcode        : old('postcode'),
        address         : old('address'),
        addresses       : [],
        hasResponse     : false,
        selectedAddress : ''
    };
},
```

So that's what I'm trying to replicate.

**I can probably replace validation with Ajax validation, but my form partial changes the appearance of fields with an error slightly, so this would be messy**

From my understanding:

- I can't set an initial data value, as this will override the input value.
- I can set a prop, but this is immutable
- Any help I can find suggests 'using a computed property which determines its value from the prop' but if you literally do that, it doesn't update.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<so-postcode-lookup initial-postcode="{{ old('postcode') }}" initial-address="{{ old('address') }}"></so-postcode-lookup>
```

---

```
/**
 * Allow user to select an address from those found in the postcode database
 */
Vue.component('so-postcode-lookup', {
    name     : 'so-postcode-lookup',
    template : '#so-postcode-lookup-template',
    props    : ['initialPostcode', 'initialAddress'],
    data     : function() {
        return {
            postcode        : '',
            address         : '',
            addresses       : [],
            hasResponse     : false,
            selectedAddress : ''
        };
    },
    computed : {
        currentAddress : function() {
            if (this.address !== '') {
                return this.address;
            } else {
                return this.initialAddress;
            }
        },
        currentPostcode : function() {
            if (this.postcode !== '') {
                return this.postcode;
            } else {
                return this.initialPostcode;
            }
        },
        hasAddresses : function() {
            return this.addresses.length;
        },
        isValidPostcode : function() {
            return this.postcode !== '' && this.postcode.length > 4;
        },
        isInvalidPostcode : function() {
            return !this.isValidPostcode;
        }
    },
    methods : {
        fetchAddresses : function() {
            var resource = this.$resource(lang.ajax.apiPath + '/postcode-lookup{/postcode}');
            var $vm      = this;
            var element  = event.currentTarget;

            // Fetch addresses from API
            resource.get({ postcode : this.postcode }).then(function(response) {
                response = response.body;

                if (response.status == 'success') {
                    // Update addresses property, allowing select to be displayed
                    $vm.addresses = response.data;
                } else {
                    $vm.addresses = [];
                }

                this.hasResponse = true;
            });
        },
        setAddress : function() {
            this.address = this.selectedAddress;
        }
    }
});
```

---

```
<template id="so-postcode-lookup-template">
    <div class="row">
        @include('partials.input', [
            'label'                  => trans('register.form.postcode'),
            'sub_type'               => 'postcode',
            'input_id'               => 'postcode',
            'autocorrect'            => false,
            'input_attributes'       => 'v-model="currentPostcode"',
            'suffix_button'          => true,
            'suffix_button_reactive' => trans('register.form.postcode_button_reactive'),
            'suffix_text'            => trans('register.form.postcode_button'),
            'required'               => true,
            'columns'                => 'col-med-50',
            'wrapper'                => 'postcode-wrapper'
        ])

        <div class="col-med-50 form__item" v-show="hasResponse">
            <label for="address-selector" class="form__label" v-show="hasAddresses">{{ trans('forms.select_address') }}</label>
            <select id="address-selector" class="form__select" v-show="hasAddresses" v-model="selectedAddress" @change="setAddress">
                <template v-for="address in addresses">
                    <option :value="address.value">@{{ address.text }}</option>
                </template>
            </select>
            <so-alert type="error" allow-close="false" v-show="!hasAddresses">{{ trans('forms.no_addresses') }}</so-alert>
        </div>

        @include('partials.input', [
            'label'            => trans('register.form.address'),
            'input_id'         => 'address',
            'type'             => 'textarea',
            'input_attributes' => 'v-model="currentAddress"',
            'required'         => true
        ])
    </div>
</template>
```

If I try this, and set the model of the inputs to currentPostcode and currentAddress respectively, I seem to get an infinite loop.

I think I'm overthinking this somehow.

Comment: `postcode: old('postcode')` Shouldn't this be `postcode        : 'old('postcode')',`?

Comment: Well in this case it doesn't matter as old is a Laravel function, so isn't accessible to the Javascript anyway (since I'm not inlining any of my Javascript or using Vueify or anything like that)

Comment: Ah, yes. My bad. It should've been  `postcode: '{{ old('postcode') }}',`.

Comment: Yeah exactly, so that's what I'm trying to emulate, somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind directly to a prop but you can set an initial value using the prop and then bind to that, which is the way to go if you need a two way binding:

```
Vue.component('my-input', {
  props: {
    'init-postcode': {
      default: ""
    }
  },
  created() {
    // copy postcode to data
    this.postcode = this.initPostcode;
  },
  data() {
    return {
      postcode: ""
    }
  },
  template: '<span><input type="text" v-model="postcode"> {{ postcode }}</span>'
});
```

Then just do:

```
<div id="app">
  <my-input init-postcode="{{ old('postcode') }}"></my-input>
</div>
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vL5nw95x/

If you are just trying to set the initial values, but don't need a two way binding, then you can reference the prop directly - as you won't be applying any changes - using `v-bind:value`:

```
Vue.component('my-input', {
  props: {
    'init-postcode': {
      default: ""
    }
  },
  template: '<span><input type="text" :value="initPostcode"> {{ postcode }}</span>'
});
```

And the markup:

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pfdgq724/

Comment: Yes! This! Created to the rescue.

Answer (score 0):

Im working in a easy way to do that using laravel 5.4 controller to send the data directly

In Laravel view:

```
 <input  class="form-control"  id="ciudad" name="ciudad" type="text"  v-model="documento.ciudad"  value="{{ old('ciudad',  isset($documento->ciudad) ? $documento->ciudad : null) }}" >
```

in vue.js 2.0

```
 data: {

    documento: {
      ciudad: $('#ciudad').val(),
    },

},
```

In Laravel Controller

```
  $documento = ReduJornada::where("id_documento",$id)->first();

  return view('documentos.redujornada')->with(compact('documento'));
```